# Correct use of enlighten as to?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I'm interested in the usage of "enlighten as to", I know "enlighten as to how..." is correct but is the following usage correct as well?

> Her aim is to **enlighten** the readers **as to discard the fact** that leaves are green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it works.

I think these variations could get your message across without the awkward wording that doesn't seem properly woven together:

> Her aim is to **enlighten** the readers **so that they will** discard the fact that leaves are green.
>
> Her aim is to **get** her readers **to discard** the fact that leaves are green.
>
> Her aim is to **enlighten** the readers **as to why** leaves are not green.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, and thank you for the suggestions. I understand my version doesn't sound usual, is it grammatically correct though especially considering the "as to discard" part?

Comment: @MaxF - I don't think so. I think we can "enlighten as to **how**..." or "enlighten as to **why**...", but I can't think of a way we can "enlighten as to `<some action verb>`".

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. Your help is highly appreciated.